# Is it possible to find out the port on which the MSI local endpoint is running?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

Is it possible to find out the port on which the MSI local endpoint is running from inside the VM using a script (PS and Shell script)?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the MSI endpoint binds to port :50342. That being said, the port can be changed in the template during deployment. You can read about the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/qs-configure-template-windows-vm

Update: We've added a new MSI endpoint, via the Azure Instance Metadata Service. This endpoint, is on a well-known non-routable IP address, only accessible form within the VM.

Here's an example on how to request a token for Azure Resource Manager, via the IMDS endpoint: 
curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F' -H Metadata:true -s

To read more about this, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/how-to-use-vm-token